# How to create a stopped Google Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How do I create a new GCE instance and not have it start up after creation?

I want to create a clone of a running instance.

No problem to create the disk from a snapshot, but creating the new instance automatically runs it and I don't see a way to stop it from doing that.

Comment: I couldn't find any way to do that. You'll probably need to create a new feature request because I didn't see an existing one for that ability either: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests

Answer (score 1):

Sadly we don't have feature to create VM instance without running it immediately. The best you can do is to add shutdown command to your [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).

Answer (score 0):

According to GCE [Instance Life Cycle](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/instance-life-cycle), after `PROVISIONING` and `STAGING` states instance always enters into `RUNNING` state, so there are no way to create stopped instance in `TERMINATED` state after `PROVISIONING` and `STAGING` states.